# JavaScript: Reduce an array to nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

So suppose my array looks like this:

```
let langArr = [
     ["python", "blue"]
    ,["python", "blue"]
    ,["c++", "red"]
    ,["java", "yellow"]
    ,["javascript", "lime"]
    ,["shell", "green"]
    ,["c++", "red"]
];
```

what I want is something like this:

```
{
  python: {
    count: 2
    color: "blue"
  }
  c++: {
    count: 2
    color: "red"
  }
  java: {
    count: 1
    color: "yellow"
  }
  and so on...
}
```

I tried reduce method like this:

```
let langCount = langArr.reduce((lang, [name, color]) => {
      lang[name] = (lang[name] || 0) + 1;
      lang[color] = 'color';
      return lang;
    }, {});
    console.log(langCount);
```

but I get this output:

```
{
  python: 2
  blue: "color"
  c++: 2
  red: "color"
  java: 1
  yellow: "color"
  and so on...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to modify the `.reduce()` snippet so it produces the output you're expecting?

Comment: You lack creation of the sub-objects, and one indirection in the reduce code. Most notably, the word `count` never occurs in your code, which should make the primary issue obvious - if you had a place to put that, you'd (probably) have the desired structure.

Comment: @Andreas that is what I tried, I don't know how to get them into separate objects

Comment: what happens if you have different colors for a language?

Comment: But you know how to use destructuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object for each language.

This approach takes an object as default value if `lang[name]` is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), like `undefined`.

The pattern

```
variable = variable || value;
```

works with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR):

- if `variable` has a [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, take this value,
- if `variable` has a *falsy* value, take `value` instead.

```js
let langArr = [["python", "blue"], ["python", "blue"], ["c++", "red"], ["java", "yellow"], ["javascript", "lime"], ["shell", "green"], ["c++", "red"]],
    langCount = langArr.reduce((lang, [name, color]) => {
        lang[name] = lang[name] || { count: 0, color };
        lang[name].count++;
        return lang;
    }, {});

console.log(langCount);
```

Comment: This is just another "group by" answer (with the little twist, that it's not an array with all options but a number for the count). This is now already enough for a new answer instead of a dupe-vote?

Comment: Thank you so much! can you also please explain what this line does `lang[name] = lang[name] || { count: 0, color };`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
array.reduce((acc, current) => {
        if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(current[0])){
            acc[current[0]] = {count: 0, color: current[1]};
        }
        acc[current[0]].count += 1;
        return acc;
    }, {});
```